# How to construct a symmetric matrix efficiently?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, matrix

I wanna construct a symmetric matrix with.

```
r=np.arange(0,11)
k=np.zeros((11,11))

for i in r:
    k[i]=np.arange(i,i-11,-1)
```

How to get rid of the for loop to construct the matrix more efficiently?

Comment: Would both the input and the operating function inside iterator be ranged arrays? Also, it doesn't look like symmetric.

Comment: Yeah, actually I'm asking the first step to construct the symmetric matrix.

Comment: `scipy.linalg.toeplitz`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this:

```
k = np.arange(0, 11)[:, np.newaxis] + np.arange(0, -11, -1)
print(k)
```

Output:

```
[[  0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9 -10]
 [  1   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8  -9]
 [  2   1   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7  -8]
 [  3   2   1   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6  -7]
 [  4   3   2   1   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5  -6]
 [  5   4   3   2   1   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  -5]
 [  6   5   4   3   2   1   0  -1  -2  -3  -4]
 [  7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0  -1  -2  -3]
 [  8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0  -1  -2]
 [  9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0  -1]
 [ 10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0]]
```

Note however this matrix is not symmetric but [antisymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix).

Another more advanced option to get the same result, but using less memory, is to create an array with numbers from 10 to -10 and "roll" through it on each row:

```
import numpy as np

def make_matrix(n):
    r = np.arange(n, -(n + 1), -1)
    s, = r.strides
    m = np.ndarray(shape=(n + 1, n + 1),
                   dtype=r.dtype,
                   buffer=r.data,
                   offset=s * n,
                   strides=(-s, s),
                   order='C')
    # Avoid writing since it is not a contiguous array
    m.flags.writeable = False
    return m

print(make_matrix(10))
# Same output
```

This only takes the memory of the first array, instead of the quadratic size of the contiguous matrix.

EDIT:

If you want to create a symmetric matrix, you can either take the absolute value:

```
k = np.abs(np.arange(0, 11)[:, np.newaxis] + np.arange(0, -11, -1))
```

Or you can modify the function above slightly like this:

```
import numpy as np

def make_matrix(n):
    a = np.arange(n + 1)
    r = np.concatenate([a[::-1], a[1:]])
    s, = r.strides
    m = np.ndarray(shape=(n + 1, n + 1),
                   dtype=r.dtype,
                   buffer=r.data,
                   offset=s * n,
                   strides=(-s, s),
                   order='C')
    m.flags.writeable = False
    return m

print(make_matrix(10))
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
 [ 1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [ 2  1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8]
 [ 3  2  1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7]
 [ 4  3  2  1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 5  4  3  2  1  0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  5  4  3  2  1  0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0  1  2  3]
 [ 8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0  1  2]
 [ 9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0  1]
 [10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0]]
```

About performance, here you have a couple of tests of contiguous vs non-contiguous in this case:

```
import numpy as np

def make_matrix_cont(n):
    return np.abs(np.arange(0, n + 1)[:, np.newaxis] + np.arange(0, -(n + 1), -1))

def make_matrix_noncont(n):
    a = np.arange(n + 1)
    r = np.concatenate([a[::-1], a[1:]])
    s, = r.strides
    m = np.ndarray(shape=(n + 1, n + 1), dtype=r.dtype, buffer=r.data, offset=s * n, strides=(-s, s), order='C')
    m.flags.writeable = False
    return m

n = 1000
k_cont = make_matrix_cont(n)
k_noncont = make_matrix_noncont(n)
print(np.all(k_cont == k_noncont))
# True

%timeit make_matrix_cont(n)
# 3.48 ms ± 42.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit make_matrix_noncont(n)
# 5.2 µs ± 11.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit k_cont.sum()
# 317 µs ± 4.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit k_noncont.sum()
# 370 µs ± 1.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit k_cont @ k_cont
# 313 ms ± 3.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit k_noncont @ k_noncont
# 417 ms ± 1.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So, in addition to taking less space, non-contiguous matrix creation is vastly faster, but summing its elements is a bit slower and matrix multiplication a bit more.

Comment: Thx, besides the way to use abs value, can the matrix be constructed as a symmetric one in another way?

Comment: @kinderchan I'm not sure what you mean by "abs value", I am not using absolute value here. Also, what are you thinking of with "can the matrix be constructed as a symmetric one in another way"? Do you mean a different method, or do you want a different result? I have added another more advanced method to get the same result using less memory (in case you want to create a really big matrix).

Comment: What I mean is using `np.abs` to get the symmetric one. Using less memory is more efficient, correct?

Comment: @kinderchan Less memory is more efficient in terms of memory, in terms of computation time, for operations that can be done with the non-contiguous array it should be similar (maybe even a bit better due to better caching? I'm not sure, not an expert on that). If the operation requires a contiguous array, it would be converted and then it would be the same as the other case. Do you want to create the symmetric matrix directly (with abs values) or you specifically want the antisymmetric one first and the symmetric later?

Comment: If possible, I prefer to create a symmetric matrix directly, but don't know how.

Comment: Less memory in terms of computation time. I'm confused. Is the array shows above contiguous or non-contiguous? Does it impact the computation time?

Comment: @kinderchan I have modified the method to make the symmetric matrix directly, and added a couple of benchmarks showing differences between contiguous and non-contiguous.

Comment: Probably not the most efficient, but possibly the most convenient way of generating this type of matrix is `scipy.linalg.toeplitz`. `linalg.toeplitz(np.arange(11))`

Comment: Thx for the contribution so much. I `%timeit` and find `scipy.linalg.toeplitz` > `make_matrix_noncont(n)` > `make_matrix_cont(n)`, but the library `scipy.linalg.toeplitz` is old and haven't been updated for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your array in a one liner.

```
np.fromfunction(lambda r,c: r-c, (11,11))
```

Result:

```
array([[  0.,  -1.,  -2.,  -3.,  -4.,  -5.,  -6.,  -7.,  -8.,  -9., -10.],
       [  1.,   0.,  -1.,  -2.,  -3.,  -4.,  -5.,  -6.,  -7.,  -8.,  -9.],
       [  2.,   1.,   0.,  -1.,  -2.,  -3.,  -4.,  -5.,  -6.,  -7.,  -8.],
       [  3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,  -1.,  -2.,  -3.,  -4.,  -5.,  -6.,  -7.],
       [  4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,  -1.,  -2.,  -3.,  -4.,  -5.,  -6.],
       [  5.,   4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,  -1.,  -2.,  -3.,  -4.,  -5.],
       [  6.,   5.,   4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,  -1.,  -2.,  -3.,  -4.],
       [  7.,   6.,   5.,   4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,  -1.,  -2.,  -3.],
       [  8.,   7.,   6.,   5.,   4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,  -1.,  -2.],
       [  9.,   8.,   7.,   6.,   5.,   4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.,  -1.],
       [ 10.,   9.,   8.,   7.,   6.,   5.,   4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.]])
```

Each cell in the array is the row number less the column number.  The first argument is a function taking row and column as arguments.  The second is the shape required.